# Adobe InDesign Animation: Properly rotate text on path

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, animation

In Adobe nDesign, I am trying to add a simple animation to a string of text on a circular path. See the screenshot below for my animation settings. The text is supposed to rotate in a circular motion around the graphic in the center. When exporting the document to `SWF`, the animation is weirdly off, see the `.gif` below to see it.

Can someone explain to me, how I can create a proper rotation of the text around the small center graphic?

[image: Animation Settings]
[image: Animation not working properly]

Answer (score 1):

The rotating animation presets  seem to create the rotation around other point than the wanted circle center. The rotation happens around the centre of the mass or at least something near that.

I have succeeded to get nearly ok result by filling the rest of the circle perimeter with paper colored text. But it's still not perfect.

Good result is achieved by using Illustrator

- prepare the text on a circle in Illustrator
- make a copy, color it to paper color (no fill do not work)
- rotate it 180 degrees and group with the visible version

Copy the symmetric version to your InDesign page and add animation.

It's useless to make a group in InDesign. The elements of the group rotate independently.

You get constant speed rotation by using preset "Spin" and selecting Speed = None.

Here's a static screenshot of properly rotating text which is copied and pasted from illustrator. It doesn't work, if the invisible (=white) counterpart was not included

[image]

**The final trick that does not need Illustrator nor invisible text:**

- select the circle and write your type on a path
- take the normal type tool T
- doubleclick inside the circle; this makes the circle also a circular text frame
- select the circle
- add the animation

I have not a slightest idea why now the center of the circle is the center of the rotation. It works - no matter, were it some text written inside the circle or not.